# Fiware IoTAgent and Context Broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm following [this example](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/backend-device-management-idas/instances) to create a simple scenario where I register a new device into the IoT Agent and it forwards it to the Context Broker. Then I want to check if the created device exists in the Context Broker, and I can seem to find it.
These are the steps I'm doing:
1. using Postman I'm sending a post request to the IoT Agent:
url: http://eidas5.lab.fi-ware.org:5371/iot/devices

```
headers: 
APIKEY:4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov
Fiware-Service:openiot
Fiware-ServicePath:/
Content-Type:application/json
Accept:application/json

body:
{
 "devices": [
    { "device_id": "DEV_ID",
      "entity_name": "ENTITY_ID",
      "entity_type": "thing",
      "protocol": "PDI-IoTA-UltraLight",
      "timezone": "Europe/Madrid",
      "attributes": [
    { "object_id": "t",
      "name": "temperature",
      "type": "int"
    } ],
  "static_attributes": [
    { "name": "att_name",
      "type": "string",
      "value": "value"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

2. Then I confirm that the device is registered with a GET request to the url http://eidas5.lab.fi-ware.org:5371/iot/devices/DEV_ID

   request headers:
   APIKEY:4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov
   Fiware-Service:openiot
   Fiware-ServicePath:/
   Content-Type:application/json
   Accept:application/json

everything seems ok so far, now I want to check where this device is in the context broker:

3. According to the docs:

> Devices will be represented as NGSI entities in the ContextBroker at 130.206.80.40:1026 (within the FIWARE service-path "OpenIoT").

So with a GET request I should be able to see the new device,but I can't. I even tryed using the fiware-servicepath and fiware-service headers as above, and I can't find it.
Any advice on this?

Answer (score 2):

fiware-service should be open-iot and fiware-servicepath /

have a look at

http://fiwaretourguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection-to-the-internet-of-things/how-to-read-measures-captured-from-iot-devices/